# textview keyboard not resigning when i press done iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

i have a textview and when i press done the textview starts a new line.

I have implemented these methods and added all the delegates

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView //was UITextField
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

i set the keyboard return key to done in attributes inspector.
i want the done key on the keyboard to resign first responder, it does not seem to work.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

    // error thrown here saying code will never execute
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
{
    return NO;
}

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return newLength <= 300;
}
```

how can i add both statements so they will work without the error?

Comment: FYI - there is no reason to call `resignFirstResponder` in the `textViewDidEndEditing:` method since that method is called only when the text view has already resigned first responder.

Comment: @rmaddy ok so if I delete those resignfirstredponder methods will it work

Comment: Remove the call to `resignFirstResponder` just from the `textViewDidEndEditing:` method. BTW - you posted one delegate method for `UITextView` and another for `UITextField`. Which one are you really using? The `textFieldShouldReturn:` method will NOT be used with a `UITextView`. It's for `UITextField`. Huge difference.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using uitextview I will change that and delete textvoewdidendediting method thanks

Comment: Please note that there is no delegate method for a text view for handling the return key like there is for s text field. The reason is simple - in a text view, the return key normally has no special meaning other than putting text on the next line. Labeling the "Return" key as "Done" makes no sense for a text view. If you only want to allow one line of text to be entered by the user, use a text field instead of a text view.

Comment: `- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textField{
// my textview is called textField.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}` this is all i have and it still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add Delegate    `UITextViewDelegate`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
```

Write this line in viewDidLoad

```
textField.delegte = self;
```

// Add below delegate method [code is in Swift. please find obj-c method and write logic as i have]

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    if (textField.text.length >= 300) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: not yet, i already have a method that limits characters in that method so when i add your method it says code will not execute

Comment: my code is in swift. i will give you obj-c. plz wait

Comment: i have 2 statements in the method, yours and a character limiting statement and it says for your statement code will not execute. can you show me how to put 2 statements in the method.

Comment: will you please show me your full code so i can give you proper solution.?

Comment: one fundamental thing -> In any returning method there is no statement will execute after return statement. (Ok dear)

Comment: can you tell me why you have wrote this - `NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return newLength <= 300;`

Comment: Because I want to limit characters, I'm new to iOS so is there any way I can add them both?

Comment: you mean you want only 300 chars in textview? Right?

Comment: And for the return key to resign first responder

Answer (score 2):

Go to your story board and then select your text field and set delegate and also confirm UITextFieldDelegate protocol in your .h file

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I set delegate in storyboard

Comment: right click on text field there is option delegate click in circle and then go to Files Owner leave mouse click.

Comment: You can do it in your .h file where it says `@interface`. It should look something like this: `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>` when you're done.

Comment: @AdrianB l i have uitextview so it says uitextviewdelegate but the keyboard still does not go when i press don it just starts a new line

Comment: remove this if you have
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone

Comment: I specified the return key in attributes inspectors so I did not put it in code